# How to check to see if steam user has a game

Tags: javascript, q, discord.js, steam-web-api

I am new to JavaScript. I am making a discord bot that gets game statistics from the steam API. I use the npm package `steam-api` and `discord.js-commando`. I can't figure out a way how to check to see if a steam user has a game.

Whenever you input a `steamID64` that has their games private or doesn't have the game it will print this in the terminal:

```
"D:\Discord Bots\statbot\node_modules\q\q.js:155
            throw e;"
```

I have been trying to solve this for a week and a half. I could not find anything to solve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Different situation, same error message](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1542)  Good luck.

Comment: Can you send us your current code please?

Comment: How about just sending an API request directly without the npm-package? I don't see why this should fail.

Answer (score 1):

The Steam API has [an API call](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/IPlayerService#GetOwnedGames) that allows you to get owned games for a user:

However, a Steam usrer can make their game list private if they so wish. If it is necessary to use your software you could [get an application ID](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth) of your own and then ask the user to allow your application to make the call using an OpenID library.